# Process builder

Tags: apex

I was trying to use a Process builder which in turn will invoke an Apex class, instead of using a trigger

Is there a way of accessing current records which are passed to Process builder from the Apex class on a custom object ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant getting data from process builer to the Apex Class.
You can pass RecordID and other fields you want as @InvokableVariable to the Invocable method in the class. Perform your logic move on.

Here is the guide.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm